# How to generate Fedex tracking numbers using APIs?

Tags: php, rest, web-services, fedex

I want to create a web service like getmoretracks.com tracktaco.com or ecomhutsy.com in these websites they find valid FedEx trackings by zip code, city, or state and also filter results by shipping status in-transit or delivered and shipping and delivery date ranges so I created FedEx developer account and API keys but not found any API like the given criteria can someone help me to reach how getmoretracks.com tracktaco.com or ecomhutsy.com these websites works or find trackings so I can also build software where I can search for trackings by date ranges and zip codes.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Full documentation:

[Fedex Developer Portal Track API](https://developer.fedex.com/api/en-jo/catalog/track/v1/docs.html)

Please check this section:

[Track By Reference](https://developer.fedex.com/api/en-jo/catalog/track/v1/docs.html#operation/Track%20by%20References)

> This endpoint returns tracking information based on alternate references other than Tracking Number such as Customer reference numbers, etc.

```
{
  "referencesInformation": {
    "type": "BILL_OF_LADING",
    "value": "56754674567546754",
    "accountNumber": "XXX61073",
    "carrierCode": "FDXE",
    "shipDateBegin": "2019-02-13",
    "shipDateEnd": "2019-02-13",
    "destinationCountryCode": "US",
    "destinationPostalCode": "75063"
  },
  "includeDetailedScans": "true"
}
```

> Specifies the reference details for the tracked shipment. The following rules apply
> Either shipper.AccountNumber or Destination.countryCode(and postal for postal aware countries) are required
> If ShipDateRangeBegin and End are not present, shipDateRangeBegin will be set to the current date minus 30 days, and shipDdateRangeEnd will default to current date plus one day.

**This applies only inside the USA.**

Comment: on this API can only search by tracking number or a reference number but I need to search by zip code, status, and dates like in getmoretracks.com

Comment: I have talked to the customer support of the website you have provided, they said they can only provide the service ( Find track by zip code and ship dates only inside USA ),

Comment: I appreciate your research I try this but how can I find a reference number? these websites getmoretracks.com, ecomhutsy.com, tracktaco.com, and gettnship.com provides the same thing and there are many more how they can provide valid trackings? I also need only inside the USA but in the JSON input the second parameter "value": "56754674567546754" this is the reference number I think how can I get that. I upvoted. @WardNsour